# Is it possible to simplify the following return statement with ternary operator?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have the following simple class and I am wonder whether it is possible to simplify it. Especially, how could I simplify the return statement? The question regards *Java 8* without optionals, and *Java 7*.

```
public static int example(String someData) {
    SomeClass sth = findSth(someData);
    return (sth != null) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (findSth(someData) != null) { return 1; } return 0;`

Comment: `return (findSth(someData)!= null) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: If there is no issue with the code then post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
return ((sth = findSth(someData)) != null).compareTo(false);
```

Comment: You haven't declared `sth` and do you even need it?

Comment: Something is wrong here, I tried to fix it, but e.g. ```return (findSth(someData) != null).compareTo(false);``` does not work at all. However the idea looks nice.